# Optimising GroupBy in PySpark

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataset where I am grouping by multiple variables to calculate the median of a max and average value for each user ID using PySpark as below:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = spark.read.parquet("s3a://xxx").select("id", "timestamp", "category", "value")
df1 = df.groupBy("id", "timestamp", "category").agg(F.max("value"))
df2 = df1.groupBy("id", "timestamp").agg(
    F.max("value").alias("max_value"), F.mean("value").alias("avg_value")
)
df3 = df2.groupBy("id").agg(
    F.expr("percentile(max_value, array(0.5))")[0].alias("median_max_value"),
    F.expr("percentile(avg_value, array(0.5))")[0].alias("median_avg_value"),
)
df3.show()
```

This is working as expected but is taking approx. 2 hours to run on billions of rows. Is there a way to optimise this?

Comment: Please add the output of ' df3.inspect(True)' to the question to show both the logical and physical query plan. Probably you can get some optimization by pre-sorting the data but without the plan it is hard to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to repartition by "id" such that the code now looks similar to:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = spark.read.parquet("s3a://xxx").select("id", "timestamp", "category", "value").repartition(F.col("id"))
df1 = df.groupBy("id", "timestamp", "category").agg(F.max("value"))
df2 = df1.groupBy("id", "timestamp").agg(
    F.max("value").alias("max_value"), F.mean("value").alias("avg_value")
)
df3 = df2.groupBy("id").agg(
    F.expr("percentile(max_value, array(0.5))")[0].alias("median_max_value"),
    F.expr("percentile(avg_value, array(0.5))")[0].alias("median_avg_value"),
)
df3.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing anything special that I would optimise. However, I would run [pandas-profiling](https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling) to see the data distribution. Maybe you could benefit by partitioning your data before the group by with a custom partitioner or use a partition function during the group by.